# RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

We have cross compiled ralink wifi usb dongle driver package "mt7601" to arm.
After successfull compilation we got a module "mt7601Usta.ko" . When we do insmod of this module in our device we are not getting any problem. After successfull insertion we are giving a command:

```
"ifconfig ra0 up &".
```

we are getting error messages in dmesg as shown below:

> [ 813.310000] RET=-110 [ 813.310000] #  [ 813.340000] RET=-110 [
>   813.340000] # [ 813.340000] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN,      Req=0x7,
>   Idx=0x1718,pAd->Flags=0x1000002

We are using linux kernel 2.6.31. Please help us to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not suffering of necrophilia and can tell you what, kernel is far too old. The error code you got is -ETIMEDOUT if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-110)*

Looks like USB bus timeout.
If this driver works on Linux PC environment(ex Ubuntu), but NOT works on your devices,  you may check your hardware first.